# Unit Testing asynchronous functions called by various didSets in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous

I'm trying to unit test a property in a ViewModel (in Swift) that is dependent on a series of other properties being set, and having trouble doing so.

I have a viewModel which includes a `timeLength`, a `timePeriod`, and a `listOfObjects` that fits my time period.

These values depend on the previous one,

`timeLength` and `timePeriod` are both stored in the user's profile, and my code follows this flow:

1. Search for a `timeLength` in the profile.
2. If none is found, allow the user to select a `timeLength`
3. Once the `timeLength` is set, a `didSet` triggers a flow that searches for a matching `timePeriod`, (in a mock repository for time periods) or creates one if one doesn't exist.
4. Once the `timePeriod` exists, a `didSet` triggers a flow that searches a database to compile a `listOfObjects` that match that `timePeriod` (using a separate mockRepository for objects).

I'm trying to create a unit test that checks the list of objects once that code flow is completed, but every time I do so, the `XCTAssertEqual` method completes before the code flow is finished. I tried using XCTestExpectation, as described in [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/testing/how-to-test-asynchronous-functions-using-expectation), but I don't have a specific asynchronous method to call, since this is all triggered by a series of `didSet` calls.

I could create a `timePeriod` in the repository, which would trigger the `listOfObjects` to be set in the ViewModel, but then I'd be missing out on the full flow of this. Is there a way to just have the test complete after a few seconds?
(Or is this a bad test since I'm relying on the system to do multiple things at once in order to pass the test?)

Here's the specific test (right now it won't do anything since there's nothing to fulfill the asynchronous wait)

```
    func testSeasonObjectsVM_loadData() {
        // given
        let exp = expectation(description: "loading Data")
        sut.timeLength = .quarter
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 20)
        
        // when
        let count = sut.listOfObjects.count
        
        // assert
        XCTAssertEqual(count, 2)
        
    }
```

Comment: "since this is all triggered by a series of `didSet` calls." Are all these `didSets` only doing synchronous stuff? If so, you don't need an expectations! Just set your first domino into place, and the rest will follow synchronously, and you can just observe the final effect directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a notification from the final place that you know the process / series of didSets has been completed like following.

```
public extension Notification.Name {
    static let UserProfileViewModelListOfObjectsLoaded =
        Notification.Name(rawValue: "UserProfileViewModelListOfObjectsLoaded")
}

// Your viewModel's final didSet
var listOfObjects: [Any] {
    didSet {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .UserProfileViewModelListOfObjectsLoaded, object: nil)
    }
}

// In your test
self.expectation(forNotification: .UserProfileViewModelListOfObjectsLoaded, object: nil) { (notification) -> Bool in
    return (sut.listOfObjects.count == 2)
}
```